# Failing to include com.typesafe in build.sbt (for Scala and spray on Heroku)

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, typesafe-stack

Trying to bootstrap my boilerplate Scala [Spray](http://spray.io/) project on Heroku, I am trying to add the necessary tweaks to my local project as per [the Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#build-sbt). The spray boilerplate project has been derived from the [excellent template at github](https://github.com/spray/spray-template) that simply works and has elegant code and tests included.

After the last mentioned template project worked great, **when adding the line `import com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin` to my `build.sbt`, any sbt command now fails with:**

`/build.sbt:1: error: object typesafe is not a member of package com
import com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin
           ^
[error] Type error in expression`

Being on Ubuntu desktop 13.04, I tried installing [the full typesafe stack](http://spectral.mscs.mu.edu/tools/typesafe/typesafe-docs/stack/html/typesafe-stack/downloading-installing.html), although everything else worked with only a local installation of a more recent version sbt till this point. But this attempt at getting this error solved doesn't change anything. Which seems in my case to place getting-ready-for-Heroku at a dead end.

I guess this integration problem may be simple to nail down, but there's too many moving parts for me here and maybe there's a simple insight that can get me unstuck here... it feels on Google like I'm probably the only one having encountered this specific problem.... but maybe the solution is dead simple for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this combination works with sbt 0.12.0 but not 0.12.4 nor 0.13.0.... changing the sbt project to 0.12.0 makes it work.