# read application.conf from build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I found a lot of similar questions, but [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998340/failing-to-include-com-typesafe-in-build-sbt-for-scala-and-spray-on-heroku) of them are unanswered and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371784/how-get-application-version-in-play-framework-and-build-sbt) don't work for me.
My task is to read application.conf from build.sbt, to keep all configuration in a single place. But my build.sbt with code

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val conf = com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

version := conf.getString("app.version")
```

don't compile with error

```
error: object typesafe is not a member of package com
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make this work it is important to know that sbt projects have a recursive structure, so when you run sbt you actually start a project that has as root folder the `project` folder within your root project.

Given that, to fix your problem you need to add `typesafe-config` as a library dependency also for you sbt project; in order to do that add a `build.sbt` in the `project` folder of your root project and specify the dependency in there as you would normally do (i.e. `libraryDependencies += ...`).

Answer (score 4):

Use this in your code

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
private val config = ConfigFactory.load()
```

and in your build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
```